# Is there a way to modularize next.js pages?

Tags: next.js

We are supposed to put all the pages of our app in the pages folder, and we can create subfolders, that is intersting.

But is there a way to have an hierarchy like this:

```
Identity
-- components
-- pages

Posts
-- components
-- pages

pages
-- index.jsx
-- (link to pages from Identity and Posts, somehow)

index.js
```

So I would like to keep related pages in separated modules/folders, and link them somehow to the main pages folder in the root directory.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you probably can create a symbolic link between those folders.

`ln -s /Users/full/path/to/posts ./pages/posts`

Comment: Nextjs doesn't seem to respect symlinks and will throw the 404 page